# Orthogonal complement in a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Each vector space $V$ can be written as  $V=W\oplus W^{\bot}$.

We can find an orthonormal basis for $W$ and $W^{\bot}$, So if we take $u\in W^{\bot}$ that means that $u{\bot}W^{\bot}$ (expect form itself) and $u{\bot}W$ fo each vector in $W^{\bot}$ and $W$?

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you're trying to ask here.

Comment: What...?${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Sorry, edited the qeustion

Comment: I think you overlooked the need to equip a vector space with an inner product in order to talk about "an orthonormal basis" or about the perpendicularity of vectors.  In its present form the Question makes almost no sense.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, let $\pmb{w} \in W$ and $\pmb{w}^{\perp} \in W^{\perp}$, then $\pmb{w} \perp \pmb{w}^{\perp}$.

Comment: Yes, is there any property for such vectors? orthogonal to their vectors basis and the orthogonal complement basis vectors?

Comment: Let the vectors in $W$ and $W^{\perp}$ be given. You could always orthogonalise a basis using Gram-Schmidt or QR decomposition. So after doing so for $W$ and $W^{\perp}$, then i hope this answers your question.